# Installed Tortoise on Win 2008 64 bit

Tags: 64-bit, windows-server-2008, tortoise-svn

I do not get context menu, I do not see Tortoise commands when I right click.

I installed TortoiseSVN-1.6.5.16974-win32-svn-1.6.5.msi

Ideas?

Answer (score 6):

You installed the 32 bit version, and the 64 bit versions of Windows require the 64 bit version of TortoiseSVN to work correctly.

From [this page](http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads), download and install the 64-bit version, reboot the machine, and it will work.

Note that you may need both the 32-bit and the 64-bit version installed if you want to make it work with other 32-bit applications, such as Total Commander.

(On 64 bit operating systems, it is possible to install both of them alongside each other.)

Comment: Just to explain the reason: 32-bit shell extensions do not work on 64-bit Windows, which is why the context menus do not appear. It used to be possible to open a 32-bit Explorer window in 64-bit Windows, through WOW64, but it does not seem to be possible anymore (I think after Vista/2008 SP2).

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could try installing the x64 version, since your operating system is also 64-bit. The version you installed is the 32-bit version.

See the [download page](http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads) for the correct link.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the 64bit version, that is why.

**Get it [here](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/tortoisesvn/TortoiseSVN-1.6.8.19260-x64-svn-1.6.11.msi?download)**

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback, really appreciate the help!
Marina

Answer (score 1):

You need the 64-bit version for it to pop up in the context menu. To get Tortoise in the Context menu from within 32-bit programs, install the 32-bit package as well. This is [the official recommendation from the Tortoise team](http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads):

> Note that x64 users can install both the 32 and 64-bit versions side by side. This will enable the TortoiseSVN features also for 32-bit applications.